# Remove TFS Connection From Visual Studio Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I am using Visual Studio 2017 and I added a TFS Server in my Visual Studio.
Every time I open my VS I get the TFS connections in my Team Explorer.

How can I remove this connection from Visual Studio? 
Note that I don't want to delete anything from the server. I only need to delete the connection from Visual Studio.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on the plug icon in Team Explorer. You should land on the tab "Connect" where you find a link" Manage Connections". Choose "Connect to a project" and you get a dialog with allyour tfs (and gihub, if you did use it) connectsion. With the "Add TFS Server" link above the list of connections you can add and remove TFS server instances.