# Remove TFS Connection From Visual Studio 2019

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, visual-studio-2019

I am trying to disconnect a TFS server and credentials from Visual Studio Team Explorer on an instance of Visual Studio 2019. I found a similar question on [Remove TFS Connection From Visual Studio Team Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55022880/remove-tfs-connection-from-visual-studio-team-explorer) which was anwsered, but these steps do not seem to apply for VS 2019. I cannot find anything to remove the existing connections. What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to Team Explorer, select the green plug symbol.

You will be able to see the connected/added list which contain both Azure DevOps Service and Azure DevOps Server in the pop-up dialog box.

Simply right click your TFS/Azure DevOps, then click **Remove**.  Then your stored server url list will be removed.

[image]

Certainly, you could also select another server/organization here to quick switch to.

This way will disconnect your TFS connection and connect to another one, and it also keep the prior stored server url in list.

Comment: When I right-click on my project name, the context menu pops up but both options (Remove and Refresh) and greyed out as inactive.

Comment: @atjoedonahue Do not right-click your project name,  you need to select the top /root of your server. In my case/screenshot, it should be **dctfs2019** and right click it. Besides, if you are connecting to  the azure devops service url like `dev.azure.com` or `{yourorganizationname}.visualstudio.com`. **It's not able to remove or refresh in the list. ** You could only remove TFS/Azure DevOps on-premise sever in the list.  Hope it's clear.

Comment: I did find a way to do it by deleting cached files, but I was really hoping to do it through the IDE. I guess no.